# Can't access S3 bucket using IAM Role from an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download a file from a private S3 bucket using the PHP SDK (on an EC2 instance).

I create an IAM role and attached the `AmazonS3FullAccess` to it.

I created the S3 bucket and this is the bucket policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::206193043625:role/MyRoleName"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::config-files/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then on the PHP side I make a curl request to `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/MyRoleName`, I get a JSON back instantiate the S3Client and try to download it, but I'm getting this error message:

> Error executing "GetObject" on "https://files.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2__config.php"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://files.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2__config.php` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
>
> AccessDenied
>
> Access DeniedC84D80 (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied -
>
> AccessDenied
>
> Access DeniedC84D80DE6B2D35FD6sDWIYK98nSH+Oa8lBH7lD91rfHospDeo0jZKFDdo0CaeY8aX6Wb/s2ja5qeYxCBuLwDJ2AqSl0=

Can anyone point me to a direction?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to access `169.254.169.254` directly. The AWS SDK for PHP will automatically retrieve credentials.

Simply create the S3 client without specifying any credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already provided ***AmazonS3FullAccess*** role to your EC2 instance, you need not to do anything else(i.e accessing metadata api). *Directly access your S3 client & it shall work as expected from your compute instance.*

Answer (score 0):

For accessing S3 Bucket from EC2 Instance follow the below steps:

```
* Create an IAM Role with S3 Full Access.
* Launch an EC2 instance with the role attached to it.
* SSH to your EC2 instance with root permissions.
* Type the command:    aws s3 ls. It will display all the buckets which are there in S3.
```

Since the role is attached to the EC2 instance, there is no need to mention the security credentials.

Thanks