# How can I enable an ec2 instance to have private access to an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

First of all i'm aware of these questions:

- [Grant EC2 instance access to S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134603/grant-ec2-instance-access-to-s3-bucket)
- [Can't access s3 bucket using IAM-role from an ec2-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330696/cant-access-s3-bucket-using-iam-role-from-an-ec2-instance)
- [Getting Access Denied when calling the PutObject operation with
  bucket-level permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272286/getting-access-denied-when-calling-the-putobject-operation-with-bucket-level-per)

but the solutions are not working for me.

I created a role "`sample_role`", attached the `AmazonS3FullAccess`-policy to it and assigned the role to the ec2-instance.

My **bucket-policy** is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::My-Account-ID:role/sample_role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

On my ec2-instance, listing my buckets works fine, both from the command line (`aws s3 ls`) and from python script.
But when I try to **upload a file** `test.txt` to my bucket, I get `AccessDenied`:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my_bucket')

with open('test.txt', "rb") as f:
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket.name, 'text.txt')
```

Error message:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Same happens when i just try to **list the objects in my bucket**. Command line `aws s3api list-objects --my_bucket` or python script:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my_bucket')

for my_bucket_object in bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object)
```

Error message:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

When I turn off "Block *all* public access" in my bucket settings and enable public access in my access control list, it obviously works. But I need to restrict access to the specified role.

What am I missing?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: s3:ListBucket is a bucket-level action. It needs a resource of `arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket` (not `arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*` which pertains to objects).

Comment: Thanks. So i added  `my_bucket/*` to my resources like: `"Resource": [            "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket", "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*" ]`, but listing the objects still fails. 
Also this is not explaning why the upload fails, right?

Comment: Stepping back, what are you trying to achieve with a policy on the S3 bucket? If you give an IAM role access to the bucket then you don't also need to allow it in the S3 bucket policy (typically you would have no bucket policy). Are you trying to restrict access to that bucket to a specific IAM role?

Comment: Yes i want to restrict access to the bucket to the IAM role speciefied in my bucket policy like so `"Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::My-Account-ID:role/sample_role"
            }`

Comment: There's an article on this topic at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

Comment: putting it simple, it would be enough to have a way to access my bucket from the ec2-instance without making it publicly available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204684/discussion-between-jarmod-and-david-salb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the problem.
The credentails of my ec2 instance were configured with the access key of a dev-user account to which the role was not assigned.

I found out by running `aws sts get-caller-identity` which returns the identity (e.g. IAM role) actually being used.

So it seems that the assigned role can be overwritten by the user identity, which makes sense.
To solve the problem, I simply undid the configuration by deleting the configuration file `~/.aws/credentials`. After that the identity changed to the assigned role.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your requirement is:

- You have an Amazon S3 bucket (`my_bucket`)
- You have an Amazon EC2 instance with an IAM Role attached
- You want to allow applications running on that EC2 instance to access `my_bucket`
- You do not want the bucket to be publicly accessible

I will also assume that you are not trying to deny other users access to the bucket if they have already been granted that access. You are purely wanting to `Allow` access to the EC2 instance, without needing to `Deny` access to other users/roles that might also have access.

You can do this by adding a policy to the IAM Role that is attached to the EC2 instance:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This grants ALL Amazon S3 permissions to the IAM Role for `my_bucket`. Note that some commands require permission on the bucket itself, while other commands require permission on the *contents* (`/*`) of the bucket.

I should also mention that **granting `s3:*` is probably too generous**, because it would allow the applications running on the instance to delete content and even **delete the bucket**, which is probably not what you wish to grant. If possible, limit the actions to only those that are necessary.

Comment: This gives me `Has prohibited field Principal`. However in the bucket policy `Principal` seems to be allowed.

Comment: Oops! Removed the role (not required within an IAM User/Role policy).

Answer (score 1):

> When I turn off "Block all public access" in my bucket settings and enable public access in my access control list, it obviously works.

Remove "enable public access" from this sentence and this will be your solution :-)

"Block all public access" blocks all public access and it doesn't matter what bucket policy you use. So uncheck this option and your bucket policy will start working as you planned.